# Confusion on what my professor was saying?

Tags: statistics

So my first lecture of a new model, deemed "Statistical Models and Methods" has begun.

We got to a point where my lecturer was talking about Parametric Models, he asks where does a model come from? And gives 3 different approaches, these being:

1. Physical argument e.g. some physical process known to give rise to a certain distribution
2. Mathematical argument e.g. central limit theorem leading to a normal distribution.
3. Flexible model, which fairly arbitrarily covers a wide range of possibilities.

He goes into further detail by looking at an example of a flexible model, i.e. the beta distribution.

He graphs the pdf f(x|alpha,beta) when alpha = beta.

I'm not sure if many will know of the specific graph, but it seems pretty likely given this is only second year course material.

The graph is symmetric about x = 1/2

He says:

"If alpha = 1, we get a uniform distribution. If alpha is less than 1 we get a bimodal distribution, where the minima of the pdf is at a half, and the maxima is at 0 and 1. If alpha is greater than 1 we get a ******* distribution and the higher we make alpha, the more peak that distribution becomes."

I've inserted the **** because I have no clue what he said here, I can't understand him. It sounds like he says "loony lome" but that's not even remotely close to anything I've heard of. It may be learning ohm, but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Could it have been "unimodal"?  This is just a guess; I don't remember anything about the beta distribution.

Comment: Checking [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Symmetric_(α_=_β)), it is indeed unimodal.